# Run Ati and Nvidia on the same computer

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up multiple GPUs (12.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152358/how-to-set-up-multiple-gpus-12-04)

On the same pc i have an ati card with one monitor plugged and a nvidia with another monitor plugged and I work in dual monitor without problems on windows 7. How I can do that in Ubuntu 12.10?

Thanks

Comment: @gertvdijk I agree this is a duplicate of that, but are you sure this cannot be done? The answer there says it cannot be done for Nvidia+Intel but that Xinerama may work with other hardware combinations.