# I'm certain Ubuntu doesn't recognise that I have two GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, hardware, gpu

The possible duplicate is regarding multiple monitor setups and intergrated GPUs, so it's unfortunately not at all relevant.

I use two GeForce GTX 780 Phantom GPUs, and I've never had a trouble running a single game. Recently that's changed, since reinstalling Steam and playing games on Linux. I use the v349.12 Edgers drivers which has definitely helped performance. However in system settings it only lists a single graphics card. I remember on Windows it always listed both cards, with a '1' or '2' appended to the end of each. Given the performance of some games, I'm sure Linux doesn't see both of them.

As always, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

[image: System Details]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up multiple GPUs (12.04)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152358/how-to-set-up-multiple-gpus-12-04)

Comment: Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351468/ubuntu-does-not-detect-second-nvidia-gpu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/606324/im-certain-ubuntu-doesnt-recognise-that-i-have-two-gpus and https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=2+gpus+ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=r8AjVa31NZP98wek5YCYDw#channel=fs&q=2+gpus+ubuntu+nvidia for some possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use that dialogue as an indication of anything.
It's just a pretty screen with high-level info.

I'd suggest using vendor-issued tools like `nvidia-settings` (GUI) or `nvidia-smi` (CLI) to work out what's there. Even neutral things like `lspci` will tell you what's plugged in.

Comment: Thanks, both GPUs are shown in Nvidia-settings. However when running anything it is clear that there is activity in 'GPU Utilization' on my first card, but not the second. I guessing that shows that there is not activity on the second card.

Comment: Also, I don't suppose I need CUDA 7 to make this work?

Comment: What activity do you expect to use multiple GPUs? The nvidia driver should map CUDA applications to all available pipelines but that requires the *application* to be use a compatible version of CUDA  (it's not a case of installing the right dev kit after the fact).

Comment: More basic multiple-GPU support like SLI is *possible*, but (anecdotally, from what I've been told) without the returns you see in Windows, so not worth it. This may change. This may have already changed. I don't have an SLI setup to know better.

Comment: I expect having both cards up and running would help with running high-end games, it's why I bought two. It seems mad to me that Linux wouldn't be capable of running both.

Comment: You're both right http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/chapter-25.html (so 2 upvotes)  **;-)**