# Ubuntu 15.04 Nvidia driver issue

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, multiple-monitors

I'm having troubles with my Nvidia drivers.

I have a GTX(660) and I use two monitors. The first one is Samsung SyncMaster(S22B150) and the second is an LG FLATRON W1934S.

The difference between them is that the Samsung monitor is plugged to my graphics card via an DVI to VGA adapter, while the Flatron is directly attached to the integrated graphics port.

Now the Flatron gets the correct resolution and is recognised by Ubuntu. On the Samsung, I get an unknown display - with 3 super small resolutions.

Also, on this new version of Ubuntu it does not show the additional drivers. The list is just empty. I've also experienced some screen flickering and mouse bugs, like the arrow getting under icons, please help me solve this "mystery."

Comment: İ believe that has something to do with multigpu support of linux

Comment: Quick research showed that it's impossible to do http://askubuntu.com/questions/152358/how-to-set-up-multiple-gpus-12-04

Comment: i'll have to attach the other monitor to my GPU, but i'll have to find an adaptor for it XD

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the correct answer doesn't solve your problem.

Currently X.org is not able to split graphics to two different video cards. A long time ago there used to be a way to do this using Xinerama, however only the proprietary drivers still support Xinerama. IOW, you can't do this if one of the GPUs is Intel Graphics.

Now, you can get this to work if you use two NVIDIA cards using -nvidia and Xinerama (or perhaps TwinView). And maybe two AMD cards using -fglrx.

However, my recommendation would be to buy a new NVIDIA card that has two outputs on it, and connect your two monitors to that. Then you can run either -nvidia or -nouveau and it should give good performance and be stable.

Of course, it would be nice if the configuration you're attempting worked. There are some efforts upstream to rearchitect X to allow it, but this is still in the development stages and may be a year or two. But if you are looking for something to spend some time on as a hobby and aren't afraid of breaking your system, you could experiment with the upstream codebases and supply them with feedback

As told in [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152358/how-to-set-up-multiple-gpus-12-04) earlier

Comment: things are changed, i've unplugged the integrated monitor so i'm left with the Samsung one. Also i have multiple output on my Gpu, but since i don't have an adaptor for them i was forced to plug it into the integrated chip.
the driver list came back, it has XServer as default, tha flickering has gone but i'm still stuck with an unknow display and a single super small res, even trying the latest test nvidia proprietary driver didn't change that much, only 3 res more, but not what i was looking for

Comment: also, i was trying to make some "test" to see what component was wrong
1) my monitor (turned out not to be it)
2) the DVI to VGA adaptor still not tested yet because i don't have another adaptor
3)my GPU (wich i hope it's not XD)
4) or my drivers